# Using Manipulate with NDSolve expression of two differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate

Hell, I am trying to model a physical system. The system composes of two partial differential equations with initial conditions defined.

I wrote the code and everything works fine, just except me trying to manipulate one of the parameters and I appreciate if anyone can suggest a solution The code is as follows.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"] (*Remove all global variables*)

gamma[alpha1_] := 1/(1 + alpha1^2);
hexternal = {1, 0, 0};

hxexternal = hexternal[[1]];
hyexternal = hexternal[[2]];
hzexternal = hexternal[[3]];

equationM1[
   alpha1_] := {M1'[t] == 
    gamma[alpha1]*(alpha1*((Cos[M1[t]]*Cos[M2[t]])*
           hxexternal + (Cos[M1[t]]*Sin[M2[t]])*hyexternal - 
          Sin[M1[t]]*hzexternal) + ((-Sin[M2[t]])*
          hxexternal + (Cos[M2[t]])*hyexternal))};
equationM2 [
   alpha1_] := {M2'[t] == 
    gamma[alpha1]*((-1/
          Sin[M1[t]])*((Cos[M1[t]]*Cos[M2[t]])*
           hxexternal + (Cos[M1[t]]*Sin[M2[t]])*hyexternal - 
          Sin[M1[t]]*hzexternal) + (alpha1/
          Sin[M1[t]])*((-Sin[M2[t]])*hxexternal + (Cos[M2[t]])*
           hyexternal))};

initial1 = {M1[0] == Pi/2 + 0.01}
initial2 = {M2[0] == Pi + 0.01}

eqns[alpha1_] := 
  Join[equationM1[alpha1], equationM2[alpha1], initial1, initial2];

Manipulate[
 sol1 = NDSolve[eqns[alpha1], {M1[t], M2[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, 
   StartingStepSize -> 1/100, 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}];
 {M1[t], M2[t]} = {M1[t], M2[t]} /. sol1[[1]];
 x = Sin[M1[t]]*Cos[M2[t]];
 y = Sin[M1[t]]*Sin[M2[t]];
 z = Cos[M1[t]];
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> 1, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}],
 {alpha1, 0.1, 1}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ParametricNDSolve` or `ParametricNDSolveValue` to get the solution before the `Manipulate` like this

```
soln = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns[alpha], {M1[t], M2[t]},
   {t, 0, 100}, alpha, StartingStepSize -> 1/100, 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}];

Manipulate[
 {M1[t], M2[t]} = soln[alpha1];
 x = Sin[M1[t]]*Cos[M2[t]];
 y = Sin[M1[t]]*Sin[M2[t]];
 z = Cos[M1[t]];
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> 1, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}], {alpha1, 0.1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much it is helpful. I have tried a lot to do such a thing in multiple ways but your answer is much simpler 

I succeeded to do it as shown in the next answer.

Comment: I am not sure if I can follow up a question on the same thread. 
Can I make it animated there is an arrow with a start at the origin point {0,0,0} and end of the arrow is the same as the curve. And rotates around the curve from the start point to the endpoint?

Comment: @AQoutb  It sounds like you want to use `Animate` and `Graphics3D` for the arrow and maybe use `Show` to combine the arrow with your `ParametricPlot3D`.  May I suggest you review the documentation for these commands and search this forum for previous questions on the subject.  You will probably get many good ideas from both.  New questions are always welcome here.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way to do it

```
sol1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[
   eqns[alpha1], {M1, M2}, {t, 0, 100}, {alpha1}];
Manipulate[
 MMalpha = sol1[alpha1];
 MM1alpha = MMalpha[[1]];
 MM2alpha = MMalpha[[2]];

 xxx = Sin[MM1alpha[t]]*Cos[MM2alpha[t]];
 yyy = Sin[MM1alpha[t]]*Sin[MM2alpha[t]];
 zzz = Cos[MM1alpha[t]];

 ParametricPlot3D[{xxx, yyy, zzz}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> 1, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}, 
   PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.007], PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
 ,
 {alpha1, 0.1, 1}]
```